# Managing a linux daemon with golang

Tags: linux, go, daemon, varnish

I need to manage the varnish service through an application in Golang, more specifically I need to have the application change the port, ip, storage method and etc.
At first I started by following the official varnish documentation (https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/tutorial/putting_varnish_on_port_80.html), so I did with that the application created the following file in the path:
/etc/systemd/system/varnish.service.d/customexec.conf

> ```
> [Service] 
> ExecStart= 
> ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :6081 -T
> localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret
> ```

There was no error, however, the service does not start
In the service status it displays the following message:

```
● varnish.service - Varnish HTTP accelerator    Loaded: loaded
(/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/varnish.service.d
           └─customexec.conf    Active: inactive (dead) since Dom 2018-01-28 15:10:46 -03; 3h 56min ago
     Docs: https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/
           man:varnishd   Process: 970 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :6081 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S
/etc/varnish/secret (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 970
(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Is there another way to manage a service across an application?

Thank you all

Comment: You have **ExecStart=** written twice?

Comment: yes, 
I did it the way the varnish documentation shows

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how golang is involved with this problem... The stuff you've posted is systemd configuration. Please clarify how Go is involved, or otherwise superuser.com might be a better place to ask this.

Comment: See [https://ma.ttias.be/running-varnish-4-x-on-systemd/](https://ma.ttias.be/running-varnish-4-x-on-systemd/)